# Can we Convert 'Figma' components to Angular components with Amplify studio?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

When we create the react or `Nextjs` application using AWS Amplify we get react components in our application in `ui-component` folder, but when we follow same process for `Vuejs`, Angular or `React-Native` application then we do not get UI components. Components are not getting pulled.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LX43.png)

Here we see in the folder structure. In `src` folder the `ui-component` folder gets created and also the Amplify folder.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGnek.png)

But When we tried same process for angular or react-native or `Vuejs` the `ui-components` folder is not pulled/generated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Hjd.png)

This is only working for react and `nextjs`. That means its `figma` components are only getting converted into react components.
Is there any different to create the same in Angular or `vuejs` or react-native.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvO0h.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) when asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

As of today Figma components can only be generated for React with Studio. We are looking to add it for Vue, Angular, and React Native in the future.

Comment: Is there a roadmap for those features?